# Local storage wont work with <input>

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm currently trying to make something work for in javascript, as u can see i made a Theater hall with javascript.

I made a big table with `<input type=checkbox>` inside the table data, with generated Id by the loop(which u can see under the `if/else` in `function tekenZaal1()`.
Now if u press the Load button i want that the checked(pressed) checkboxes will be added to local storage.

I've try some but it won't work, it adds only 1 string to to the local storage with 
key: undefined 
and 
value: undefined.
i've no idea how to fix this what's wrong with my code?
btw: i couldn't get jsfiddle to work with my code idk why but i have a screenshot of my full html and javascript code of the theather hall: http://gyazo.com/a9a3d23ee12e1862e447fab02075446a

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Reserveringspagina</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="check.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="reserveringsjavadeel1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="tekenZaal1()">
        <div id="content">
        </div>  
        <div id="containergroot">
        <div id="content1"></div>
        <div id="content2">
        </div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="addStorage()">load</button>
        </body>     
    </html>
```

javascript:

```
var zaal1 = 
[ //Array van zaal1//
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0],
[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0],
[0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,0],
[0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,0],
[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0],
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
];

//Variabelen die worden weergegeven in de <p> die aangemaakt wordt als je op een stoel klikt//


//functie die zaal1 tekent//
function tekenZaal1()
 { 

var zaal = "";

     zaal+="<table border='0' id='tabel'>";

for(i = 0; i < zaal1.length; i++){

    zaal+='<tr>';

   for (j = 0; j < zaal1[i].length; j++){


    if (zaal1[i][j] == 1){ 
         zaal+='<td class="prijslaag"><input title="rij'+(i+1)+'stoel'+j+'" type="checkbox" class="stoel1" id="rij'+i+'stoel'+j+'" name="choice" value="7,50" onchange="bereken(1 , checked, Blauw)"></td>';
    }
    else if  (zaal1[i][j] == 2){
         zaal+='<td class="prijsmiddel"><input title="rij'+(i+1)+'stoel'+j+'" type="checkbox" class="stoel2" id="rij'+i+'stoel'+j+'" name="choice" value="9" onchange="bereken(2, checked, Oranje)"></td>';
    }
    else if  (zaal1[i][j] == 3){
        zaal+='<td class="prijshoog"><input title="rij'+(i+1)+'stoel'+j+'" type="checkbox" class="stoel3 "id="rij'+i+'stoel'+j+'" name="choice" value="11" onchange="bereken(3 , checked, Rood)"></td>';
    } 
    else {
         zaal+='<td><img src="witlogo.png" width="40" height="40"></td>';
    } 

}

       zaal+="</tr>";
    } 

       zaal+="</table><br>";

        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML+= zaal;
} 
function bereken(type, checked, kleur) {


if (checked) {
    if (type == 1) {
    prijs += 7.50;
    }
    else if (type == 2) {
    prijs += 9;
    }
    else if (type == 3) {
    prijs += 11;
    }
    //Maakt een <p> en zet daar de aangeklikte stoel in//
    var para = document.createElement('p');
    para.id = ('stoel'+ type);
    var node = document.createTextNode(kleur);
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("content1");
        element.appendChild(para);
}
else {
    if (type == 1) {
    prijs -= 7.50;  
    }

    else if (type == 2) {
    prijs -= 9;

    }
    else if (type == 3) {
    prijs -= 11;

    }
    // Verwijderd de desbetreffende <p>stoel die is aangemaakt//
    para = document.getElementById('stoel'+type);
        para.parentElement.removeChild(para);

}

document.getElementById("content2").innerHTML = "<p id='prijstotaal'>\u20ac"+" "+prijs+"</p>";

}

function addStorage() {
    var stoelen = ['rij'+i+"stoel"+j+""]
    var zaal = ['zaal1', 'zaal2', 'zaal3']

        if ("localStorage" in window) {
            localStorage.setItem(stoelen.value, zaal.value);
            alert("localstorage set");
        }
        else {
            alert("no localStorage in window");
        }
}
```

Comment: what do you expect `zaal.value` to do?

Comment: getting the value from var zaal. But i think i made some huge mistake there

Comment: `zaal.value == undefined`. `zaal` does not have a property `value`...

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you mean by "the value from var zaal"?

Comment: I tought that in local storage u need a key and a value, i dont think zaal.value can work now but i dont know how to do it  the right way

Comment: In plain English, what value do you want to store in local storage?

Comment: Value="7,50" for the numbers 1 in the array value="9" for the numbers 2 in the array  and value="11" for the numbers 3 in the array? does that make anything clear or should I be more specefic?